# How to get angular speed in SUMO simulation

Tags: sumo

I'm a new user of SUMO. I use SUMO to simulate my V2X project.
To estimate the future state of vehicle, I need the current position, speed and angular speed of vehicle in SUMO simulation.

I already get the position and speed from traci api, but I don't find the angular speed api. 
current angle is got, but no current angular speed.

```
traci.vehicle.subscribe(vehID, (tc.VAR_ROAD_ID,
   tc.VAR_LANEPOSITION,
   tc.VAR_POSITION3D,
   tc.POSITION_2D,
   tc.VAR_POSITION,
   tc.VAR_SPEED, 
   tc.VAR_ACCELERATION, 
   tc.VAR_ANGLE))
```

How do I get the angular speed in SUMO simulation? If there is no angular speed, does SUMO have the current track radius for me to caculate the angular speed?

Answer (score 0):

The majority of inputs for sumo networks consists of linear edge segments and does not have an information on radius so the sumo network does not store it by default (and thus the vehicle does not have it as well). There are approximations to third order polygons when writing openDrive output, see http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Networks/Further_Outputs#OpenDRIVE_Road_Networks but you are probably equally well off guessing the radius yourself.